# in Pyomo, How to write a constraint that has different time periods based on another parameter?

Tags: pyomo

I'm working on a purchasing optimization model, below are some related inputs:

**stets :**

- model.b = Set(initialize=Brands, doc='Brands')
- model.s = Set(initialize=Suppliers, doc='Suppliers')
- model.t = Set(initialize=Time , doc='Time in days')

**parameters:**

- model.lt = Param(model.s, initialize=LeadTime, doc='Lead time to buy from supplier (s) in days')

**variables:**

- model.q = Var(model.b, model.t, model.s, domain=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0.0,None), doc='Recived quantity of each brand (b), at time (t), form supplier (s).')
- model.pr = Var(model.b, model.t, model.s, domain=NonNegativeIntegers, bounds=(0.0,None), doc='Purshase Order quantity of each brand (b), at time (t), form supplier (s).')

I'm struggling to write a constraint that makes quantity ordered before (LT) days from time (t) = quantity received now at time (t),  where LT is the lead time required by each supplier. 
This is how I imagine the **constraint** but I don't know how to write it:

*quantity ordered at time (t - lead time) = quantity received at time (t)        ,  for all times (t), brands (b), and suppliers (s)*

Your time and help are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the time points in the model are all integers and that subtracting the lead time from one point in `model.t` will give another valid index of `model.t`, then the following should work:

```
def compute_received(m,b,t,s):
    if t - m.lt[s] < min(m.t):
        # Deliveries at this time would have to be placed before the beginning of the model
        return Constraint.Skip
    return m.q[b,t,s] == m.pr[b,t-m.lt[s],s]
model.compute_received = Constraint(model.b, model.t, model.s, rule=compute_received)
```